# Forcing scalar products to avoid prescribed values

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime, and $n\ge 1$ an integer number. Suppose that the (not necessarily distinct) vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_N \in{\mathbb F}_p^n$ satisfy the following condition:

> \begin{gather}
> \text{For any $f_1,\dotsc,f_N\in\mathbb F_p$, there exists $z\in\mathbb F_p^n$ such that} \\
>   \langle v_1,z\rangle\ne f_1,\dotsc,\langle v_N,z\rangle\ne f_N. \tag{$\ast$}
> \end{gather}

How large can $N$ be under this assumption?

Denoting the largest possible value of $N$ by $N(p,n)$, one has $N(p,1)=p-1$. In general, $N(p,n)\ge(p-1)n$, as follows by taking $(v_j)$ to be the sequence containing $p-1$ instances of every basis vector; how sharp is this bound?

Incidentally, ($\ast$) implies that for any subspace $L\le\mathbb F_p^n$ there are at most $|L|-1$ indices $j\in[1,N]$ with $v_j\in L$, but this does not lead to any reasonable upper bound for $N(p,n)$.

Comment: The obvious upper bound is $np\log p$ (every next choice of $f_j$  can be made to reduce the available set of $z$ by $1/p$ of its size). I'm not sure which of the two trivial bounds is closer to the truth though...

Comment: $b_j$ and $v_j$ denote the same thing, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Right, fixed!

Comment: I would say, for any $d$-dimensional subspace $L$ there are at most $N(p,d)$ indices $j$ with $v_j\in L$...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: I would expect something of this sort, but this does not seem immediate to me: inside $L$, you are limited with the choice of $z$.

Comment: You do not need to limit yourself in that way. In fact, the vectors $v_i$ and $z$ live in _different_ spaces (dual to each other), so for the subspace $L$ with many vectors you are seeking for $z\in L^*$ which cannot be found.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: I agree. Basically, you say that for any $z\in\mathbb F_p^n$ there is $z_0\in L$ such that $\langle v,z\rangle=\langle v,z_0\rangle$ for any $v\in L$.

Comment: No, that's not true (check $L$ being the linear hull of $(1,1)$ in $\mathbb F_2^2$). I say that your problem can be reformulated in the dual language: let $V=\mathbb F_p^n$; we want to find $v_i\in V^*$ such that for any $f_i\in \mathbb F_p$ there is $z\in V$ with $v_i(z)\neq f_n$. Now, if some subset $L$ of $V^*$ has too many elements, then $z$ for those $v_j$ should be found modulo $L^0$, i.e., in $L^*$ (here we may choose $L^*$ to be any $(\dim L)$-dimensional subspace of $V$ on which $L$ .acts non-degenerately, i.e., any direct complement of $L^0$),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86186/discussion-between-seva-and-ilya-bogdanov).

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, it would be great if you could formally answer the question here. Thanks.