# Covering the finite plane with lines

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields, finite-geometry

This is, essentially, a geometrically rendered version of [the question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/315973/9924) I asked a week ago, with the emphases slightly shifted; it seems more natural and appealing (to me, at least) in this form.

Let $p\ge 3$ be a prime number. Suppose we are given $N$ lines $l_1,\dotsc,l_N\subset\mathbb F_p^2$, and we want to translate them to get new lines $l_1',\dotsc,l_N'$ (which are either parallel, or identical to the original lines) so as to have the whole vector space $\mathbb F_p^2$ covered by these new lines: $l_1'\cup\dotsb\cup l_N'=\mathbb F_p^2$. This can be impossible if $N\le2(p-1)$, as it follows by considering the system of $p-1$ "vertical" and $p-1$ "horizontal" lines. Is this always possible if $N\ge 2p-1$?

More generally, given $(p-1)n+1$ affine hyperplanes in $\mathbb F_p^n$, can one always translate them so that the resulting translates cover the whole space $\mathbb F_p^n$?

Comment: This is true for lines with three distinct directions. Already for four directions (say, vertical, horizontal, parallel to $x\pm y=0$) not clear for me.

Comment: @FedorPetrov The answer to the question, as posed, is "certainly not". If $N(p)$ is the minimal $N$ with the property that any $N$ lines can be shifted to cover $\mathbb F_p^2$, then $\lim_{p\to\infty}(N(p)-2p)=+\infty$. The trick is to consider $p-3$ vertical lines, $p-b$ horizontal lines and choose all other directions more or less at random, so it would be pretty hard to cover any $3\times b$ rectangular arrangement by just $b+C$ lines. However, I still do not know even if $N\ge 2.00001p$ would suffice for large enough $p$.

Comment: @fedja: Could you expand your remark (the "pretty hard to cover" statement) and, maybe, convert it to an answer?

Comment: @Seva Sure. I just wanted to prove something more interesting but since you asked and since I'm failing so far, I'll do it later today.

Comment: @FedorPetrov For the 4 directions you consider, lines $x=k$, $y=k$, $x+y=k$ and $x-y=k$ for $-p/4 < k < p/4$ cover all points in $\mathbb{F}_p^2$. (Consider cases based on which of the intervals $(-p/2,-p/4)$, $(-p/4,p/4)$ and $(p/4, p/2)$ has a representative of $x$, and of $y$, in them.) But if you take $a \approx \sqrt{p}$ and look at lines parallel to $x=0$, $y=0$, $x=y$ and $x = ay$, I don't know what happens.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer sure, they cover, but what if you fix different number of lines in these four directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C>0$ be any fixed number. Take $p-3$ horizontal lines and $p-b$ vertical lines where $p\gg b\gg C$. If we want to stay within $2p+C-3$ lines, we should be able to cover some $3\times b$ rectangular configuration by at most $b+C$ lines of any prescribed slopes $a_1,\dots, a_{b+C}\ne 0$. Notice that we have $3b$ points to cover and each line can cover at most $3$ points, so we can afford only $3C$ lines that cover $2$ points or fewer. Thus some $b-2C$ lines should pass through $3$ points.

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_b$ be the base of our $3\times b$ configuration and $u,v,w$ be its "vertical side". Then for each slanted line coming through $3$ points, we have some triple $i,j,k$ such that 
$$
(w-u)(x_j-x_i)=(v-u)(x_k-x_i) \tag {$*$}
$$ 
and the slope of the corresponding line is determined by that triple. Notice also that those triples cover at least $b-6C$ indices $1,\dots,b$ (the indices not taken by the exceptional $3C$ lines). Thus we can choose $\frac b3-2C$ linearly independent equations of the type ($*$) (just take an equation including some index not used yet every time until you run out of them). There are some $K(b)$ possible arrangements of those equations and $p^3$ choices of $u,v,w$, so we see that we can have at most $K(b)p^{3+\frac 23b+2C}$ arrangements that are coverable by $b+C$ slanted lines in principle and all slopes (and even lines) except $3C$ are determined by $x_j$ and the ($*$)-equations up to the order. That results in the bound $K(b)(b+C)!p^{3+\frac 23b+5C}$ for the number of choices of $b+C$ slopes that can be used to cover *any* $3\times b$ configuration, which falls short of $(p-1)^{b+C}$ available choices if $b\gg C$ and $p>p(b)$.

If you do it carefully, you get the lower bound of the type $N(p)\ge 2p+p^\alpha$ for large $p$ with some $\alpha\in(0,1)$, but it is still only a rather pitiful improvement of the trivial lower bound $2p-1$, so I didn't try to be very precise in the estimates.